# How do I open different sessions in tabs instead of windows?

Tags: jprofiler

In JProfiler I want to have multiple tabs open in the same window, where each tab is a different session. Currently, each session is opening in a new window and creating clutter on my desktop.

I am on Mac, and I have the system setting "Pref tabs when openning documents" set to "Always". However, JProfiler is still openning sessions in separate windows.

Answer (score 1):

As of 13.x, this is not possible. I've added an issue to JProfiler's issue tracker.